# Intrinsically Ergodic Factor

Tags: measure-theory, ergodic-theory

Let $(X,T)$ and $(Y,S)$ be two intrinsically ergodic system with the same topological entropy i.e. $\exists ! \mu, \exists ! \nu$ measures of maximal entropy such that $h_\mu(T)=h_{top}(T)=h_{top}(S)=h_\nu(S)$. 
Proove that if $\pi:(X,T)\rightarrow (Y,S)$ is a factor i.e. $\pi$ is continuous, surjective and $\pi \circ T=S\circ \pi$, then $\pi\mu=\nu$.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I didn't miss anything, these steps seem to work:

1. Prove that there is a probability measure $\nu'$ on $X$ such that $\pi\nu' = \nu$.
2. Prove that there is an invariant probability measure $\nu'$ on $(X, T)$ such that $\pi\nu' = \nu$.
3. Prove that $h(\nu') \ge h(\nu)$.
4. Prove that $\nu'$ is *a* measure of maximal entropy, hence *the* measure of maximal entropy on $(X, T)$.